# Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Range("O26") sometimes turns up a blank dialogue box

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub to save my doc as a binary workbook. (Got from Stack Overflow.)

I tried taking the value from a cell to use as the file name.

Usually it works fine, I cannot figure out why sometimes not.

My data in cell O26 is always a text string.

```vb
Dim fname As Variant
Dim FileFormatValue As Long

fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Range("O26"), filefilter:= _
  " Excel Macro Free Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx," & _
  " Excel Macro Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm," & _
  " Excel 2000-2003 Workbook (*.xls), *.xls," & _
  " Excel Binary Workbook (*.xlsb), *.xlsb", _
  FilterIndex:=4, Title:="Save as xlsb")
'Find the correct FileFormat that match the choice in the "Save as type" list
Select Case LCase(Right(fname, Len(fname) - InStrRev(fname, ".", , 1)))
    Case "xls": FileFormatValue = 56
    Case "xlsx": FileFormatValue = 51
    Case "xlsm": FileFormatValue = 52
    Case "xlsb": FileFormatValue = 50
    Case Else: FileFormatValue = 0
End Select

If fname = isblank Then
    MsgBox "Project Not Saved!"
    Exit Sub
End If
         
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fname, FileFormat:= _
  FileFormatValue, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Where did you get `If fname = isblank` from? That is off.

Comment: I added that to warn the user if the process of saving wasn't completed... thats not were my issue is, that part works. Its the beggining ```(InitialFileName:=Range("O26")``` where I added the ```Range("O26")``` in place of just quotation marks that I don't get, it worked at first but now it just comes up blank

Comment: Best to specify what worksheet and workbook that `Range` is on.

Comment: I changed it to```(InitialFileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O26")``` and it still doesn't work

Comment: If I do ```InitialFileName:="Merchant"``` then I'll get "Merchant" as my file name, but I tried also replacing it with a variable and that also didnt work

Comment: Best to be explicit about the `.Value` too.

Comment: I don't have any ```.Value``` in my code. And in case you didn't notice it yet, I'm super newbie at this.

Comment: Add `.Value` after `Range("O26")`.

Comment: I added it and it still doesn't work

Comment: I'm just stumped because it worked perfectly fine in one workbook but in the next one it doesnt and its the same code

Comment: Most likely `ActiveWorkbook` is not the one you want.

Comment: I definitely want the ```ActiveWorkbook``` I am running it from a shortcut button directly in the excel workbook, and the merchant name is in the workbook I am working on in cell O26!

Comment: Then `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O26").Value` to confirm it's the value you want.

Comment: Yes it is what I want

Comment: I just tried adding ```x = Range("o26")``` and then changing it to
 ```fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=x, filefilter:= _```
When I hover over the ```x``` in both places, I see the merchant name, but the dialogue box is still blank.

Comment: On a side note... I actually ran into this myself just a few days ago. From the docs: When InitialFilename is used with an extension and a filter is applied, this extension must match the filter extension, otherwise the effective InitialFilename displayed in the dialog box will be an empty string.... that's most likely your issue.

Comment: @BigBen Oh wow! I am realizing now that the merchant I keep having issues with has their DBA as their website, so it must be getting confused with the '.com'... I added .xlsb and now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond simple! I just needed to add .xlsb to my text string in Cell O26!
Now my extension matches the filtered extension.
(The initial value in Cell O26 is a formula, so adding it is not a big deal, I just included it in the formula.)

Answer (score 1):

### GetSaveAsFilename

- The star of your code is [Application.GetSaveAsFilename method
  (Excel) | Microsoft
  Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getsaveasfilename).

**The Three Sentences**

- Displays the standard `Save As` dialog box and gets a file name from
      the user without actually saving any files.
- (This method returns the selected file name or the name entered by
  the user. The returned name may include a path specification).
  Returns **`False`** if the user cancels the dialog box.
- When `InitialFilename` is used **with an extension** and a **filter is
  applied**, **this extension must match the filter extension**,
  otherwise the effective `InitialFilename` displayed in the dialog
  box will be an empty string.

**The issues**

- No need to use case sensitivity on a dot (`.`): 
  Not `InStrRev(fName, ".", , 1)`, but `InStrRev(fName, ".")`.
- There is no `isblank` in VBA (it's all lower case anyway). `ISBLANK` is an
  Excel Function. The 2nd sentence addresses this issue (`False`).
- The 3rd sentence is basically saying that you have to use either a
  filename without an extension or with the extension specified by
  `FilterIndex` which is `xlsb` in your case. If you need to have a
  file with another extension, then you can use a combination of `Left`
  and the newly created `getExtension` to get the filename without an
  extension.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

' Gets the extension (the string behind the last dot) of a filename.
Function getExtension(ByVal fName As String) As String
    getExtension = LCase(Right(fName, Len(fName) - InStrRev(fName, ".")))
End Function

' DisplayAlerts Version
Sub getSaveFileDA()

    Dim fName As Variant
    Dim FileFormatValue As Long

    With Application
        fName = .GetSaveAsFilename( _
                InitialFileName:=Range("O26").Value, FileFilter:= _
                " Excel Macro Free Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx," & _
                " Excel Macro Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm," & _
                " Excel 2000-2003 Workbook (*.xls), *.xls," & _
                " Excel Binary Workbook (*.xlsb), *.xlsb", _
                FilterIndex:=4, Title:="Save as .xlsb")
    End With

    ' Find the correct FileFormat that matches the choice
    ' in the "Save as type" list.
    Select Case getExtension(fName)
        Case "xls": FileFormatValue = 56
        Case "xlsx": FileFormatValue = 51
        Case "xlsm": FileFormatValue = 52
        Case "xlsb": FileFormatValue = 50
        Case Else: FileFormatValue = 0
    End Select

    If fName = False Then         ' When user selects Cancel.
        MsgBox "Project Not Saved!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' If fName exists then Excel will complain about it and when you
    ' press No or Cancel, an error will occur. To prevent this you can
    ' use Application.DisplayAlerts but keep in mind that then the file
    ' will be overwritten without the confirmation dialog popping up.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fName, FileFormat:= _
                          FileFormatValue, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    MsgBox "Project successfully saved.", vbInformation

End Sub

' On Error Resume Next Version
Sub getSaveFileOE()

    Dim fName As Variant
    Dim FileFormatValue As Long

    With Application
        fName = .GetSaveAsFilename( _
                InitialFileName:=Range("O26").Value, FileFilter:= _
                " Excel Macro Free Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx," & _
                " Excel Macro Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm," & _
                " Excel 2000-2003 Workbook (*.xls), *.xls," & _
                " Excel Binary Workbook (*.xlsb), *.xlsb", _
                FilterIndex:=4, Title:="Save as .xlsb")
    End With

    ' Find the correct FileFormat that matches the choice
    ' in the "Save as type" list.
    Select Case getExtension(fName)
        Case "xls": FileFormatValue = 56
        Case "xlsx": FileFormatValue = 51
        Case "xlsm": FileFormatValue = 52
        Case "xlsb": FileFormatValue = 50
        Case Else: FileFormatValue = 0
    End Select

    If fName = False Then GoTo NotSaved ' When user selects Cancel.

    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fName, FileFormat:= _
                          FileFormatValue, CreateBackup:=False

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        GoTo NotSaved
    Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "Project successfully saved.", vbInformation
    End If

    Exit Sub

NotSaved:
    MsgBox "Project Not Saved!", vbExclamation

End Sub
```

Comment: Longer code, same empty dialogue box.
I guess I should resign myself to doing this one step manually.

Comment: @Shevy: Could you tell me what exactly do you have in cell `O26`?

Comment: `When InitialFilename is used with an extension and a filter is applied, this extension must match the filter extension, otherwise the effective InitialFilename displayed in the dialog box will be an empty string.` - I'm guessing this is the issue (had the same issue myself).